# Parse JSON object in postgresql (Migrating from MongoDB to PSQL)

Tags: json, mongodb, postgresql

I've been using [pgfutter](https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter) to import a JSON file to     postgresql.

Now I am trying to parse that json file to my psql table. This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE organisation (
id int8 PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
department VARCHAR(255),
business_type VARCHAR(255),
unit_active INTEGER 
);
```

This is an example of my json:

```
{
"extension":[
{
    "name":"unitActive",
    "value":"Active"
},
{ 
    "name" : "businessType",
    "value" : "Other" 
},
{
    "name":"specialities",
    "value":[
    {
        "value":"allm kirurgi"
    },
    {
        "value":"neurologi"
    },
    {
        "value":"ortopedisk kirurgi"
    }]
}],
"catalog":"main",
"department":"hospital"
}
```

I've been looking at the postgresql [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) but i'm not quite sure how to normalize the object, in this case the extension object in my JSON.

This is what I got

```
INSERT INTO organisation
SELECT nextval('organisationsSequence'), 
data->>'department' as department, 
"Something here" as business_type,  
"Something here" as unit_active
FROM import.collection WHERE data->>'catalog' = 'main';
```

So what i'm trying to achieve is to do something like "Select extension.value where extension.name = businessType"

Comment: Well... I solved this by writing a java application which did migration for me instead..